# UISlider set Image with corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Here I need to rounded uslider but when i try to set images it shows rectangled image,

I need like this Image[image]

Here My coding

```
UIImage *volumeBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"l2.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 5, 7, 5)];
    [self.audioSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"l1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 5, 7, 5)]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.audioSlider setMaximumTrackImage:volumeBackgroundImage
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.audioSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderhandle.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Could anybody help to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have images with round corners. For example: 
[image]

Then simply use this image like this:

```
[_slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"black_dot.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12)]
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_dot.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12) 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

(where black_dot.png is example image, and blue_dot.png would be the same but in blue color)

(If image is pixelated - then You need to get this image twice as big - retina image - `black_dot@2x.png`)

(Or in case You actually need smaller image than given example, then just rename this image as `black_dot@2x.png`,  and instead of :  `UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12)`   use:  `UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)`)

See more info here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/8656216/894671

Answer (score 1):

You can try to draw the image of the size required, rather than adding a image which might cause distortion.

[Slider distortion solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54283173/5336761)

Answer (score 0):

I think this occurs because the round end is generated by the UISlider natively. It assumes that the thumb image will cover the end at extreme positions so it will not redraw it.

One solution could be to take care of the rounding at the end yourself:

```
self.audioSlider.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

Experiment with this value and it should work.

Alternatively, you could make sure your images have rounded ends.

Comment: no sir, Its not working still it returns the same result.I s there any solution

Comment: Which solution did you try? Both?

Comment: In first they return same results
In Second when i place the rounded edge images its shows as pixalated image

Comment: So it seems it is enough to give the images a higher resolution.