# UISlider strange behavior

Tags: swift, uislider

When I customized UISlider and override the `minimumTrackTintColor`, `maximumTrackTintColor`, and `trackHeight`, I noticed the slider had a strange offset when the value approaches the end of the slider.

However, there is no offset when slider is in the middle range. Any idea how to fix it?

Offset when approaching the end:
[image: slider offset]

Normal in the middle range:
[image: normal slider]

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656122/iphone-custom-uislider-preload-and-rounded-edges-issues) out

Comment: @AquilaSagitta thanks, but in my case, I am using `maximumTrackTintColor ` and `minimumTrackTintColor ` - instead of picture. Any idea how could I fix it without using a circular icon?

Comment: Other than making the slider icon a round image you could try playing with slider frame maybe. Why don't you want to use round image?

Comment: changed to image - works like a charm. thank you @AquilaSagitta